# How would I include a namespace in an included file?

Tags: php, routes, slim

I'm currently building a project to learn the Slim framework. I have a pretty good basic understanding of Slim but namespaces are still quite confusing to me. I'm storing my routes in separate files based on what page they relate to (home, about, add, etc). The issue is that I cannot create a `Request` or `Response` object without using

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
```

at the top of each route file. Is there a way I can put the `use` at the top of my main routes file and have every included file use it?

For example, my `routes.php` file is included in my `start.php` file which is included in my `index.php`. Inside my routes file has includes to each specific route `home.php, about.php, add.php, etc`. Each file included in my `routes.php` has to have a `use` statement otherwise I cannot access `Response` and `Request` without namespacing them.

Comment: No that isn't possible in PHP. See  [SO Namespaces examples](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/1021/namespaces), [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), and [What are namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384204/what-are-namespaces/3384384#3384384).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Rude explanation - "Use statement belongs to file" (In case we are not using multiplie namespace declarations in file, which is not recommended). Nor you can't extend namespace using require/include.

```
test.php: 
    include "MyString.php"; 
    print ","; 
    print strlen("Hello world!"); 
MyString.php: 
    namespace MyFramework\String; 
    function strlen($str) { 
        return \strlen($str)*2;
    } 
    print strlen("Hello world!");
```

> Output: 24,12

But you can instantiate your objects once in the namespace. And they will be available in other files of the namespace.

```
test.php:
    namespace App;
    include "request.php";
    var_dump($request); //$request object is available here
request.php
    namespace App;
    use \Http\Request as Request;
    $request = new Request();
```

Also, there should be dependency container in Slim framework. Maybe you can put your objects here. Not familiar with the framework, so feel free to correct me.