# Trying to understand what is namespaces: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'feline\Cat' not found in C:\Users\bird\

Tags: php, namespaces

Trying to understand what is namespaces, and what is point of using them, and where to use them, and how to use them..

Code:

```
<?php 
namespace foo;

class Cat {
    static function says() {echo 'meoow';}  
} 

namespace bar;
class Dog {
    static function says() {echo 'ruff';}  
} 

namespace animate;
class Animal {
    static function breathes() {echo 'air';}  
} 


use foo as feline;
use bar as canine;
use animate;

echo \feline\Cat::says(), "<br />\n";
echo \canine\Dog::says(), "<br />\n";
echo \animate\Animal::breathes(), "<br />\n"; 

?>
```

Getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'feline\Cat' not found in C:\Users\bird\
```

Comment: `echo feline\Cat::says(), "<br />\n";` loose the first backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is caused by your first backslashses at:

```
echo \feline\Cat::says(), "<br />\n";
echo \canine\Dog::says(), "<br />\n";
echo \animate\Animal::breathes(), "<br />\n";
```

change it into:

```
echo feline\Cat::says(), "<br />\n";
echo canine\Dog::says(), "<br />\n";
echo animate\Animal::breathes(), "<br />\n";
```

and it should fix your error

**What are namespaces** ?
Namespaces are the way of encapsulating items.

**Why namespaces?**
Building your application with OOP ( object-orientated programming ) is the way to go, you don't need to re-write your code every single time because you can re-use your code, this is what namespaces can do without any name conflicts.

Here is the post that explains your question
- [What are namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384204/what-are-namespaces)

**Examples on how to use them**
Here are a few examples and tutorials you can follow to understand it better.
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-namespace/
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

If you want to learn php and the use of OOP I recommend you to use Laravel.
https://www.laravel.com