# PHP sub-namespaces usage

Tags: php, namespaces

PHP and namespaces.

I assume that i missunderstood its correct usage/idea..
(please read to the end)
I have two files: `1.php`, `2.php`

1.php:

```
namespace App\someNS;

class classname{}
```

2.php:

```
namespace App;
include_once("1.php");
use App\someNS; // tried to comment it also, not working

$ x = new classname();
// this fails..
```

My assumption is that namespaces are containers\scope, so by including one - I can access its content;
I expected that the `use App\someNS` will "include" it.

I know that someNS\classname() will work, but I fails to see the big advantage in namespaces if the only "profit" from them, is the options to use the same names for variables, if after all i still need to use a path to get them... what am i missing?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384204/what-are-namespaces may give some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces, `use` and including files are actually three different things:

- A namespace is just a prefix that allows to reuse the same class and functions names in different parts of your code base.
- The `use` statement only creates an alias so you don't need to type the full name (namespace + local name) or you can all the object with a different name. It doesn't import or load code.
- `include` is what actually makes code from other files available, but it has existed for years before namespaces were implemented in PHP.

Said that, your code should throw:

> Class 'App\classname' not found in ...\2.php

That's because your `use` alias is for the namespace, so you'd need to call:

```
new someNS\classname();
```

To be able to do `new classname()` you need to alias the class:

```
use App\someNS\classname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces work like directories and files in your filesystem.

You can enter a directory and execute a file:

```
cd /var/www/project

phpunit SomeTest
```

Or you can execute the file passing the whole path:

```
/var/www/project/phpunit SomeTest
```

In your example, you can use:

```
//class2
namespace App;

include_once('1.php');
use App\someNS\classname;

$x = new classname();
```

Or

```
//class2
namespace App;

include_once('1.php');
use App\someNS;

$x = new someNS\classname();
```

Or even

```
//class2
namespace App;

include_once('1.php');

$x = new someNS\classname();
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.basics.php)